# Documentation for Objective C and Cocoa APIs?

Tags: objective-c

Super-newbie question!

I've been looking for a list of all the classes that come with Objective-C and Cocoa but can't seem to find one.

Hoping that it has matching methods and syntax(?) as well.

Be gentle with me!

Thanks,
Spencer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start here: http://developer.apple.com/referencelibrary/Cocoa/index.html

The system is broken up into frameworks, so you will not find a single listing. It depends on which frameworks you include with your project. good luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using XCode, there's a documentation browser (Help -> Documentation) that's searchable. If you want to browse by classes you can also do so here. You might need to subscribe or download the documentation first though.

I'm finding this very convenient for iPhone development at least, since I can just type in a class or method name and get its documentation very quickly. YMMV for Mac OS X documentation though since I haven't used that at all.